# Tailwind form with button at bottom of screen should be above keyboard

Tags: html, mobile, tailwind-css

I have this page with a textarea and button. The button should always be at the bottom of the screen so that the texarea takes full height of the screen.
However on mobile when you click in the textarea the keyboard shows up and I want the textarea to be the height until the keyboard so that the button is before the keyboard starts.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/3udbOmpHrS

However I am struggling to get this right. Any ideas?
I have an attached a screenshot of the idea im looking for. So that the Submit button I have shows above the keyboard area so it is always available to the user.
[image]